Unable to with-redefs a var from another namespace in Clojure test fixtures
I'm trying to redefine a JWT secret in my test fixtures but having trouble getting with-redefs to work correctly with a var from another namespace.
Current Setup
I have a JWT secret defined in my pathom namespace (app.model.user.pathom)
;; In app.model.user.pathom
(def jwt-secret "production-secret")

In my tests, I'm trying to override this with a test secret using test fixtures:
;; In test namespace
(ns app.model.user.pathom-test
  (:require [app.model.user.pathom :refer [jwt-secret]]))

(def test-jwt-secret "test-secret")

(defn with-jwt-secret [f]
  (with-redefs [jwt-secret test-jwt-secret]
    (f)))

(use-fixtures :each (join-fixtures [db-cleanup-fixture
                                  email-fixture
                                  with-fixed-time
                                  with-jwt-secret]))

It's being used like this
(defn generate-token [user-id client-type]
  (jwt/sign claims jwt-secret {:alg :hs256})))

The Problem
The redefinition doesn't seem to take effect - the original production secret is still being used in the tests. This is evidenced by JWT validation errors in our tests:
Caused by: clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Message seems corrupt or manipulated

The test passes correctly if i manually change the test value to equal the production value.
What I've Tried

Using the fully qualified namespace:

(with-redefs [app.model.user.pathom/jwt-secret test-jwt-secret]
 (f))

2.Using the reader macro:
(with-redefs [#'app.model.user.pathom/jwt-secret test-jwt-secret]
  (f))

which results in the error Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class clojure.lang.Cons cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.Symbol (clojure.lang.Cons and clojure.lang.Symbol are in unnamed module of loader 'a pp') 

I then made sure i was Requiring and referring the var:

(:require [app.model.user.pathom :refer [jwt-secret]])

(with-redefs [#'jwt-secret test-jwt-secret]
  (f))

Still getting the same error as in 2. above
Still getting the same JWT validation errors.
Environment

Clojure 1.11
Using Pathom 3
Using buddy-sign for JWT handling

Question
How can I properly redefine this var in my test fixtures? What am I missing in my namespace handling or var resolution?

Do any of your other fixtures use jwt-secret directly in their setup or teardown code? It looks to me like you've wrapped with-jwt-secret as the innermost fixture, so it's established only around the test functions themselves, not around any other fixtures.

no it's not being used by other fixtures

Move your jwt-secret to your env in pathom
currently:
(def jwt-secret ...)
(pco/defresolver authed [_ _]
  {::pco/output [::authed]}
  ;; if not throw, authed
  (buddy/unsign jwt-token ...)
  {::authed true})

Recommended
(pco/defresolver authed [{::keys [jwt-secrect]} _]
  {::pco/output [::authed]}
  ;; if not throw, authed
  (buddy/unsign jwt-token ...)
  {::authed true})

This makes easier to you to control/replace the var during the tests :)
